# CSS Clearfix not working, even with after element

Tags: html, css

I have a clearfix that is added to any element with the classname `group`
In the following screenshot you can see 2 things

1. on the bottom right, you see that the clearfix was succesfully added to the flash div, as there was an `after` element created.
2. You see the title `New post` clearly moving to the right side of the flash message div. To make it more clear, I indicated the margin of the flash div in red

[image: clearfix]

```html
div.alert {
    width: 10rem;
    margin: 3rem;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

edit;
Since I didn't state it explicitly, I was hoping to understand why the clearfix didn't span the whole width of the parent container.
In the meanwhile, Pete has already provided me with a sattisfying answer, and that is that I should add the clearfix to a parent container, rather than to the floating flash element itself.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with the relevant coding?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: can you create a sample [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the point of `:after`.  It will put the content at the end of the specified element (not after it), so using a `:after` to clear the float on the floated element itself will not clear it as the clear will be put inside that element.

To fix this either add `clear:left` to the new post div styles or wrap the flash div in an element with the clear fix on it

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, one follow up question though: Why doesn't it work to add clear:right on my flash div?

Comment: Because your div is floated left, you need to clear the float so `clear:left` or `clear:both`